# Implicit conversion still happens even I use NSTextAlignmentCenter

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Before change the code :

```
[titleLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
```

Now :

```
[titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
```

After change the code, the warning still appears. I wanna ask why this happens? 
Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: Doesn't appear for me on Xcode 5.1.

Comment: try clean and rebuild

Comment: Thanks for your fast respond, I did and the warning still appears

Comment: Click the Product menu.. hold the Option Key... then choose Clean Build Folder. Then rebuild... see if it still persists.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did and i find all warning disappear. However, I do not want other warning disappear.

Comment: Thanks for reading and answer. I find out the solution : delete the sub folders of deriveddata and all things go right.